# Why on disabled Pseudo class background color of icon button is not changing

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

Carousel is working fine. But the issue is when there is no card on left the js function add disabled class to the `left-arrow` but  on disabled i want the background color of icon to be dim and disabled. Don't know how can I fix it. Is there a way to change the bg color on disabled.

[image]

html:

```
   <div class="left-arrow" id="left-arrow-rtl">
              <div class="arrow" >
                 <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
              </div>
   </div>
```

Css:

```
.left-arrow :disabled{
  background-color: grey;
}

.left-arrow {

  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #ACBBD1;
  border-radius: 60px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo class disabled only works on input fields , buttons and select.
By adding the background color to disabled class it works.

```
.disabled {
  background: #ACBBD1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: :disabled also works on other input elements, like button and select

Comment: you may want to use `.left-arrow.disabled` to ensure it is more specific than the `.left-arrow` style.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey why i add the bg to disabled so it will work for both right and left without adding specific class for right and left